# Span text wrap align with the first line

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I am having difficulties to align the second line of the span, to align with the first line, when there is a wrap happening.

```
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="20" height="20">
<rect width="20" height="20" style="fill:rgb(0,167,206);"/>
<text x="50%" y="14" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="10">'
 +(+counter)+ '</text></svg></div>' + " "+ "<b>
<span style='margin-left:20px;'>" + data[i].metadata.LocationName+"</span></b>"
```

How can I align the text in second line with the first line. Here is how it looks. Any help is appreciated. The text that is showing is dynamic from a service, so I can't determine the length of the text.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the numbers in the circles/square have `float: left;`. If you can access them, delete the `float: left;` and apply `display: inline-block` instead. This will prevent the subsequent text from floating under it.

Comment: Thanks buddy! You saved me the rest of the day